# MATLAB exist('resources', 'dir') found directory. What is it, and where is it really located?

Tags: windows, matlab, path, directory

I have been writing a MATLAB script for handling a lot of files and variables for my thesis work. One thing I do is storing the work directories on a file. Working with this have lead me to a lot of trouble with lines equivalent to

```
exist('resources', 'dir') == 7
```

I am not that experienced with Windows directories not aimed toward end users, I thought this would surely fail since it does not look like a valid path on any drive. However, it does succeed finding a folder. I suspect there are more of these directories. Or is it a folder in MATLAB's search paths?

What are they? And **where** are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a folder on Matlab search path, likely this one:

```
exist([matlabroot '/toolbox/simulink/simulink/resources'], 'dir') == 7
```

I guess what you want is a subfolder relative to `pwd`, then you can do

```
exist('./resources', 'dir') == 7 % work for all OS
```

to check if the folder exists.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for some new level of hidden directories I could explore ;) 

Thank you for your input! It makes sence. I am not sure I can use that last line though. I encounter this when I am trying to change directories saved in a .mat-file via a MATLAB function with user input. The user inputs that he/she wants to change a certain directory (exploring name-pair input), then a check is done to make sure that the inputted path is in fact valid. If `resources` is inputted as the wanted directory, this problem occurs (it passes the test). For now I solved it by forbidding that input.

Comment: One more question though. `exist` founds it, but `dir` does not. Do you know why? Does not `dir` make use of MATLABs search paths?

Comment: `dir` works for a specific folder, and does not search over matlab path.